# How can I get a list of all packages with their license from a Podfile.lock?

Tags: licensing, podfile, podfile-lock

Due to compliance reasons, I need to generate a list of all software packages we use with their licenses. Also for indirect (transitive) dependencies.

I know how to do the same with Python using `pkg.get_metadata_lines("PKG-INFO")` or for JavaScript using `yarn licenses`, but I have no clue how to do it with a Podfile.lock.

Given a Podfile.lock, how can I do something like this:

```
$ get-licenses Podfile.lock
BigInt==1.2.3;MIT
CryptoSwift==4.5.6;Apache License 2.0
SwiftProtobuf==1.3.5;BSDv3
```

Comment: Is it allowed to use Python for example?

Comment: Sure! I only want a list of packages with their license as the output (if possible, their transitive closure, so all dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

- First variant (I didn't check this): use ["cocoapods-lockfile-parser"](https://github.com/snyk/cocoapods-lockfile-parser) (or try to use [Snyk](https://github.com/snyk)).
- Second variant (I didn't check this): you can use [ADLicenseLint](https://github.com/faberNovel/ad_licenselint/), but you need Podfile too, [not only Podfile.lock](https://fabernovel.github.io/2020-09-09/linting-licenses).
- Third variant: use PyYAML + NetworkX.

Python example to get transitive dependencies:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yaml


def fetch_connected_nodes(g, node, seen=None):
    if seen is None:
        seen = set()

    for nr in g.neighbors(node):
        if nr != node and nr not in seen:
            seen.add(nr)
            fetch_connected_nodes(g, nr, seen)

    return seen


def make_pod_graph(pods: dict, package_name: str):
    pod_graph: nx.DiGraph = nx.DiGraph()

    def add_pods(pod, parent):
        parent = parent.split(' ')[0]
        if isinstance(pod, dict):
            # Really only 1 key in the dict.
            for k, v in pod.items():
                add_pods(k, parent)
                add_pods(v, k)
        elif isinstance(pod, list):
            for i in pod:
                add_pods(i, parent)
        else:
            pod_params = pod.split(' ')
            pod_graph.add_node(pod_params[0])
            attrs = {'version': ''.join(pod_params[1:]).strip('()=')} if len(pod_params) > 1 else None

            if parent is not None:
                pod_graph.add_edge(parent, pod_params[0], attr=attrs)

    for p in pods:
        add_pods(p, package_name)

    return pod_graph


with open('Podfile.lock', 'r') as pod_file_lock:
    pod_data = yaml.safe_load(pod_file_lock)
    g_pod = make_pod_graph(pod_data['PODS'], 'Podfile.lock')

    for s in g_pod.neighbors('Podfile.lock'):
        print(f'{s};{";".join(fetch_connected_nodes(g_pod, s))}')

    # nx.draw(g_pod, with_labels=True, pos=nx.shell_layout(g_pod))
    # plt.show()
```

Result for [this file](https://github.com/snyk/cocoapods-lockfile-parser/blob/master/test/lib/fixtures/iina/Podfile.lock):

```
GRMustache.swift;
GzipSwift;
Just;
PromiseKit;PromiseKit/CorePromise;PromiseKit/UIKit;PromiseKit/Foundation
PromiseKit/CorePromise;
PromiseKit/Foundation;PromiseKit/CorePromise
Sparkle;
```

You can get licenses using `DEPENDENCIES` or `EXTERNAL SOURCES` sections.
Just find specific files in repos.
Or, if you can find those packages using the OS package system (and then use, for example `yarn licenses list`, on them), that's an option.